# laravel firstOrNew doesn't work when using mutator for date

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I'm trying to prevent importing duplicate records from csv file, everything is fine when checking for all items, but when I want to check for duplicate date, it doesn't work because in the model I'm using mutator function to change date format.

```
public function setPostingdateAttribute($date) {
    $this->attributes['postingdate'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('n/j/Y', $date)->format('Y/m/d');
}
```

in function for implementing importing csv file

```
$data = array_combine($escapedHeader, $columns);
$details = $data['details'];
$postingdate = $data['postingdate'];
$slip = $data['checkorslip'];
$addchecks = Checks::firstOrNew(['postingdate'=>$postingdate]);
$addchecks->details = $details;
$addchecks->slip = $slip;
$addchecks->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is know issue, as far as I remember I've created Pull request in past that will fix it but it was declined (or raised this on Laravel github)  so in case you use mutators using `firstOrNew` or `firstOrCreate` might get you unexpected results.

Comment: I've found it! Take a look at discussion at https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14649 If it doesn't work you might need to manually verify in database if record already exists and insert it only when it doesn't